# How can I get the classname at runtime, but only the classname?

Tags: java

How can I get the classname at runtime, but only the actual classname and not the whole "com.xyz.etc." ?

I mean only the part of the name after the last period

Comment: If you are talking about getting it as a String, you could use StringTokenizer

Comment: yes, that's why I asked the question because I was thinking this too - but that there must be something easier than that.. getSimpleName() was what I was after, not sure why I didn't see that in the docs.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to use this snippet code for object:

```
yourObject.getClass().getSimpleName();
```

or for class use :

```
yourClass.class.getSimpleName();
```

this code return only name of class, does not consist package name.

Answer (score 3):

```
String className = object.getClass().getSimpleName();
```

http://www.coderanch.com/t/410851/java/java/Class-Name