# How to get class name at run time in testng

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am having `@BeforeClass` annotated method in BaseClass. I am trying to get the name of current execution class(Child class to BaseClass) at **runtime**.

Do we have any mechanism to get the class name from its Baseclass at runtime?

I am able to get the class name when I am trying to run single class, but facing issue while running multiple classes. Getting same class name for all the classes in the report.

Comment: Post code example, it's unclear what you want to achieve atm.

Comment: java.lang.Object.getClass() https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/object_getclass.htm

Comment: instanceof https://www.javatpoint.com/downcasting-with-instanceof-operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer this link 
[How can I get the classname at runtime, but only the classname?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148010/how-can-i-get-the-classname-at-runtime-but-only-the-classname)

If you want to get super class name  you can use getSuperClass().

Comment: If an answer to another question can be used here, please do not answer the question and flag it as a duplicate (if you have enough privileges).

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of TestNg ITestContext object here:

```
Class x = ctx.getSuite().getAllMethods().listIterator.next.getRealClass();
//Then just take it as a String

String name = x.getName().substring(x.getName().lastIndexOf(“.”)+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String getClassName(ITestContext iTestContext) {

    return iTestContext.getCurrentXmlTest().getClasses().stream()
               .findFirst().get().getName();
}
```

Or you could retrieve the class itself by:

```
iTestContext.getAllTestMethods()[0].getInstance().getClass();
```